# How to handle a HANDLE return in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, type-conversion

I have got a C++ code which I want to use on C#. One of the methods returns HANDLE type and I do not what to do with it. My code is this one:

```
[DllImport("CloudMeshDll.dll")]
public static extern HANDLE GethNextColorFrameEvent();
```

Can I replace HANDLE with any other type like I did for Char* (IntPr) or HRESULT (Int32)?

Thank you.

Comment: Use IntPtr.  What you are supposed to do with it is something you'll have to ask the owner of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the Win32 API [`HANDLE` is defined as `void*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#HANDLE). Now, unless you use `unsafe`, C# doesn't have pointer types. So the standard way to deal with this is to map `HANDLE` (and similar types) to `IntPtr`, because `IntPtr` is pointer sized. That is it is 32 bits wide in a 32 bit process, and 64 bits wide in a 64 bit process.